# Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 (Anaconda/Windows)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, anaconda, setuptools

I am running Anaconda, trying to install nanopack with `pip install nanopack`.  It fetches all the packages, but then I get the following:

```
(base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install nanopack
Collecting nanopack
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/54/24/f5b5a96a6a32d1127eb547745ab9572286035058f60a2988bdd2b1673bd7/nanopack-1.0.0.tar.gz
Collecting NanoPlot>=0.20.1 (from nanopack)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7d/aa/cc3e03a0da80b3d05df7dcfb04ae8f29b4a6015f98654be105cc0dc54fb5/NanoPlot-1.19.0.tar.gz
Collecting NanoStat>=0.6.1 (from nanopack)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9c/8e/3fd581ebe737d1bf6716e5e8731f6677a84ab71bb0291b0cf8f1a9c6b656/NanoStat-1.1.2.tar.gz
Collecting NanoFilt>=1.5.2 (from nanopack)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/dc/4a/dacdbbd28973d2d56ad0c0f3bf578f2bdfb68c9d27d7828034ea05cc90bc/NanoFilt-2.2.0.tar.gz
Collecting NanoLyse>=0.2.1 (from nanopack)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e9/52/812e19f50576871e82c0f5e8f188f4a7de99199fe1ceb50c33ac353de408/NanoLyse-1.1.0.tar.gz
Collecting nanoget>=0.15.0 (from nanopack)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7b/45/a161033155c3b55907bbb3dc85025c005390601c291dbdb1f483693750db/nanoget-1.7.4.tar.gz
Collecting nanomath>=0.13.3 (from nanopack)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/19/0b/2cdf6f70b6b7e581b7149b60f9117841326186d44aa62f60ed18280f7515/nanomath-0.22.0.tar.gz
Collecting nanoplotter>=0.16.5 (from nanopack)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7f/ed/0283c5a58f61ea9af971123c325dfea26d84e7eec2159bbc8852dc783368/nanoplotter-1.1.1.tar.gz
Collecting NanoComp>=0.4.0 (from nanopack)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a6/a2/a9d201685eef0f5d0da3d4729a20a53ae3e427cbb4fbbea060dd14e9ea96/NanoComp-0.23.1.tar.gz
Collecting NanoGUI (from nanopack)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bd/a1/6cf74f2086e4e7215c740c28671337f01d126e9d2f4ec6ebacc47fd792de/NanoGUI-0.1.0.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: biopython in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from NanoPlot>=0.20.1->nanopack) (1.72)
Collecting pysam>0.10.0.0 (from NanoPlot>=0.20.1->nanopack)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/73/59/c319f1bde3019bbce4583cecb12b9e3e52ffcfbe2c96d8b1fb131c0d4fb7/pysam-0.15.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
    '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
    # pysam: cython is available - using cythonize if necessary
    # pysam: htslib mode is shared
    # pysam: HTSLIB_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS=None
    # pysam: htslib configure options: None
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\mlsyring\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h3benh6k\pysam\setup.py", line 223, in <module>
        htslib_make_options = run_make_print_config()
      File "C:\Users\mlsyring\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h3benh6k\pysam\setup.py", line 69, in run_make_print_config
        stdout = subprocess.check_output(["make", "-s", "print-config"])
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 389, in check_output
        **kwargs).stdout
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 466, in run
        with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 769, in __init__
        restore_signals, start_new_session)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1172, in _execute_child
        startupinfo)
    FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\mlsyring\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h3benh6k\pysam\
```

I updated setuptools (as other forums mentioned) with `pip install --upgrade setuptools`, and tried `pip3` but I still get the error.  I also updated python to 3.7.1 (others had issues less then 3.6.6), setuptools v40.5.0, and Anaconda py37_0.  No clue what else I can update/do.
Any idea how to fix this? I can get other packages to install, just not nanopack...

Comment: See https://github.com/pysam-developers/pysam/issues/353